# setOnClickListener perde a animação padrão

Tags: java, android

Ao definir o setOnClickListener para definir a ação de um item de minha listview, a animação padrão do click na lista é perdida. Gostaria de manter a a animação e executar a minha rotina.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource, parent, false);
    item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //MyActions
        }
    });
    return item;
}
```

Tentei algo como super.onClick mas não deu certo.
Alguém saberia como resolver?

Valeeu!

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Boa noite amigo.... provavelmente a sua listView está perdendo foco. isso se dá se no caso os itens da sua listView conter Buttons ou imageButtons. Observe se este é o seu caso. Se sim, adicione a propriedade no xml do Button ou do imageButton: ``focusableInTouch="false"``

Comment: Obrigado pelo retorno amigo. O item que exibo é exatamente este que está no gif. Em todo caso coloquei o android:focusableInTouchMode="false" no ImageView, mas não solucionou. Para fazer o gif comentei a parte que adiciona o listener e aí o efeito do click volta a funcionar normal. De toda forma muito obrigado pela força.

Answer (score 0):

Tente usar o `AdapterView.OnItemClickListener` na listView para manusear os cliques. Descarte o onClickListener do item no getView do seu adapter por enquanto.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    View item = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(resource, parent, false);
    // ...
    return item;
}
```

Defina o OnItemClickListener na sua ListView

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        // TODO: substituir "object" pela classe usada para popular a lista
        Object itemClicado = (Object) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
    }
});
```